# Is there a way to add a secondary outerLayout?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to add a landing page to my apostrophe-cms site. I add a view in apostrophe-pages called "landing.html". 
The page should not use the outerLayout. I want to define a outerLayoutExtra that I can inherit from. 
Is there is a way to define extra Layouts from which i can extend?

```
{% extends data.outerLayoutExtra %}
```

did not find my template that i put in apostrophe-templates/views on its own. Is there is a config for templates that I have to expand?

Thanks for any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 2):

[This page in the Apostrophe docs](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/editing-page-templates.html#creating-and-extending-page-templates) has more information about data.outerLayout and extending templates.

An example of possible template inheritance:

- `default.html > defaultLayout.html > data.outerLayout`
- `landing.html > landingLayout.html > data.outerLayout`

`data.outerLayout` is used in certain situations where Apostrophe needs to reload just the content of the page, so it does need to be at the end of each template stack.

Answer (score 0):

Just straight forward:

```
{% extends "apostrophe-templates:outerLayoutExtra.html" %}
```